# Retrieve deleted file from GIT

Tags: git, visual-studio

I am new to git. I have stashed my changed before starting to work on other branch. When I was done with that I came back and saw my stash. One new file is missing from the stash that I added, rest of the files are there. I also deleted that file from `Changes` since I though it is safe in `stash`. Is there any way to get that file back?

Comment: have you ever `git add` that file?

Comment: @farhad I just found that I have commited it into a branch. I can see the branch in reflog

Comment: it's good if you even added that file sometime, somewhere you could find it out in .git/objects but that was weird :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you've never added that file, it's almost gone but if you have, here is a weird way to find it.

Run this command where your '.git' folder is.

```
find .git/objects | sed -n 's_.git/objects/\(.\{2\}\)/\(.*\)_\1\2_p' | xargs -n1 git cat-file -p | grep "content" -A 20 -B 20
```

And Replace `content` with something that you know it was in your file content.

Hopefully, You'll find that file then you can change -A and -B params to print the whole file.

## Explanation:

- First, we extract all git objects files with `find`.
- Then we generate the hash name of the object with `sed`
- Then we print out the content of every object using `xargs` and `git cat-file` and search for the `blob` containing the file we want.

Comment: This is the best help I have received in my professional career. Thanks a lot.

Comment: You're a god! I found my lost university homework from 5 years ago with this command

Comment: @MohMah Seriously? :)), thanks for the editing btw I can't believe that was `comment` all this time

Comment: Powershell: The term 'sed' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.

Comment: Bash: the command runs for about 40 seconds then completes, but nothing was printed to the window and no new file was created? What am I looking for and where?